# Need to return two values in a For loop with if/else statement

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this homework in my school where I need to separate the numbers and the letters and print them apart. My problem is I can only return one value which is the number not the letters in my if/else statement, I need to return both values so I can print the numbers and the letters separately.

Any suggestion on how I could do it with only one method?

```
public static String Separation(String output) {
    String number = "";
    String letter = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
        char x = output.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
            number += x;
        } else {
            letter += x;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271731/whats-the-best-way-to-return-a-pair-of-values-in-java

Comment: Unrelated: method names go camelCase in java, and should include a verb, in your case `separateDigitsAndLetters()` or something alike.

Comment: Just wondering: is something still unclear here, or why didn't you accept an answer so far?

Answer (score 10):

You could do things like:

- return an array of String: `return new String[] { number, letter };`
- or return a List of String: `return Arrays.asList(number, letter)`

Or, more OOP: you create a small class that holds **two** Strings, like:

```
class Entry {
  String number;
  String letter;
...
```

and then you return an instance of that class. Of course, you have to adapt the signature of your method accordingly, to use the desired return type instead of `public String ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Result {
   private String number;
   private String letter;

   public Result(String number, String letter) {
      this.number = number;
      this.letter = letter;
   }

   public void setNumber(String number) {
      this.number = number;
   }

   public void setLetter(String letter) {
      this.letter = letter;
   }

   public String getNumber() {
      return number;
   }

   public String getLetter() {
      return letter;
   }
}
```

then

```
public static Result Separation(String output) {
   String number = "";
'  String letter = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
       char x = output.charAt(i);
       if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
           number += x;
       } else {
           letter += x;
       }
   }
   return new Result(number, letter);
}
```

**Edited:**
Change from c# to java

Comment: Here it is @GhostCat, deleted because I saw there are almost the same answers here, so didn't wanted to overload with similar things. If you think it can be deleted, leave a comment. Cheers!

Comment: You were still coming in early, and all of that makes sense, so just keep it ;-) ... the more interesting part would be to get the OP to accept one of the answers, but far too often the newbies just come in, ask a question, get an answer ... and walk away.

Answer (score 1):

> … I need to separate the numbers and the letters and print them apart.

Do you really need a static method that returns something?

```
public class WTF {

    String number;
    String letter;

    public void separation(String output) {
        number = "";
        letter = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
            char x = output.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
                number += x;
            } else {
                letter += x;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        WTF wtf = new WTF();
        wtf.separation("2 to 5 the jury decides");
        System.out.println(wtf.number + " " + wtf.letter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use two separate lists, one for numbers and other for letters.

Comment: It won't solve the problem that is "return two objects".