# What is the most Java-compliant way to return more than one type in a method?

Tags: java

Say I have a Java method where I need to return different types based on a condition. For simplicity I'll provide a really dummy example:

```
public (something goes here) processSomething() {
    if (condition1) {
        return true;
    } else if (condition2) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return new ComplexObject();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm not defining the return type to avoid assumptions about the solutions. I know that there are options such as generic types, `Any` and `Object` (I may be misinterpreting some of those that may not work for my use case).

The intention is to use the return of the aforementioned method to invoke other methods that have predefined arguments (such as `int`, `boolean` and `String`) using Java's reflection API (invoke).

I wanted to know what is the most recommended one by Java experts.

Comment: [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051182/what-is-a-data-transfer-object-dto)

Comment: While this is ultimately opinion based, I think the vast majority of java developers would just tell you to not write methods like that. Why not return some custom "ProcessResult" object which can have all this information encapsulated in it?

Comment: What would the caller do with the result? This seems like a strange question to ask. [XY problem?](https://xyproblem.info/) Can you elaborate on why you need this?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I totally agree, and this is exactly what I have now, but the requirement of the application is to have the specific types rather than a custom result. But I get your point, and it is a very good one

Comment: "is to have the specific types" but what you're asking for here is _the least_ specific type.

Comment: @luizbarcelos Can you elaborate on how you plan on using the results from the method call?  How will you know which is returned from the other side?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll update the question to better explain my intent with the result of this function

Comment: I'd suggest adding code showing how you call this method and how you deal with the return value. That may help with a more specific recommendation in your case.

Comment: `Object` is too generic, and I would not recommend it, since it basically reduces the type safety of this code significantly. I'd suggest using either the Interface related to the return type or a parent class of the return type(s) for this kind of method.

Comment: The situation you describe suggests a poor design within your app. If you were to supply a practical example, we might be able to point out an alternate design that avoids this code debacle. With a proper design the type system in Java should be helping, not hampering.

Comment: reflection [invoke takes a bunch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) of `Object`s, so Object is probably right.

Comment: I reopened because [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55517826/642706) is *not* a duplicate of this Question. The other question asks about retuning *multiple* values, while this Question is about returning *single* value of *various types*.

Answer (score 7):

Create a "result holder" class. Something like this:

```
class OperationResult {
  boolean flag;
  ComplexObject info;
}
```

Also, it is technically possible to use (checked) exceptions for various outcomes, but it is unlikely such pattern is a good choice.

Comment: yes a new class is the best option, think about developers that will maintain your code after you

Answer (score 2):

Since Java doesn't support union types when specifying return types (an unfortunate oversight, given that it supports them elsewhere), you must specify a single return type.

Depending on how the callers wish to respond to the different values, various options exist:

- if the callers wish to treat all types the same, define a common superinterface for the types that allows that caller to do so, and return that one
- if the caller wish to detect and distinguish the types, you can:

  - return Object, document the types, and have them use `instanceof`. This is not type safe, i.e. the compiler will not warn if you check against the wrong type, or if a refactoring has changed the type
  - return a type that provides getters for all possibilites as well as means to discover which value was set. This is more type safe, but requires some care to be safe if a refactoring were to add additional types later.
  - pass the value in typesafe callbacks that the caller provides to you, or return a value that accepts a visitor. This requires more setup, and using callbacks may be inconvenient for the caller, but it does allow for type safe switching of arbitrary types
  - pass the typical value by returning it, and atypical values by throwing them, possibly using checked exceptions. This is slightly easier for the caller than using callbacks, but still rather cumbersome. There is also a slight runtime cost in capturing the stacktrace (which you could disable, but that might be unexpected), so using this for very frequent occurrences may be suboptimal. This approach is particularly suitable if the exceptional values typically cause the caller to abort what it is doing and escalate the exception to its callers.

An example for the second technique:

```
 class FooReturn {
   enum Type {
       number, 
       bool, 
       complex
   }
   
   final Type type;
   int number;
   boolean bool;
   ComplexType complex;

   FooReturn(int x) {
     type = number;
     number = x;
   }

   // other constructor and getters
}
```

The use of an enum allows typesafe switching, and which will alert the caller if possible types are added or removed in a later refactoring:

```
var value = foo(42);
switch (value.getType()) {
    case number:
        int n = value.getNumber();
        // deal with it
        return whatever;
    case bool:
        if (value.getBool()) {
            return doThis();
        } else {
            return doThat();
        }
    case complex:
        var c = value.getComplex();
        return doSomethingComplex(c);
}
throw new AssertionError("Unexpected type: " + value);
```

The caller may also use if-statements, of course:

```
var value = foo(42);
if (value.getType() == FooReturn.Type.number) {
    dealWithNumbers(42);
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("This should not be possible :-/");
}
```

This doesn't offer exhaustiveness checking, but can be useful if you only need to deal with a small subset of cases.

**Edit**

> The intention is to use the return of the aforementioned method to invoke other methods that have predefined arguments (such as int, boolean and String) using Java's reflection API (invoke).

That probably doesn't require distinguishing or type safety. Since `Method.invoke` takes an `Object[]` as argument, I'd simply return that array, so the caller can do:

```
myMethod.invoke(foo(42));
```

If the foo method knows the method being invoked, having it return a lambda might more sense, because it might allow bypassing the reflection thing and therefore be more type safe:

```
foo(42).run();
```

where foo is being defined like

```
Runnable foo(int x) {
    if (x == 42) {
        return () -> someObject.methodOne();
    } else {
        return () -> someObject.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a java expert, but I think that the best way to pass a value that could be one type from a lot of types would be an Object.
Java provides wrapper classes for primitives values, so you're free to use Objects for them too.
Once you return that object, you surely wanna know which type is and you can know it using `.getClass()` method.
I know that you wanted an expert opinion, but I'm pretty sure that it will be something similar of what i said.

Answer (score -2):

Converting the other data types to the Object Datatype.

```
public class types {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(multipleTypes(5));
    }
   static  Object multipleTypes(Object num){
       Object numb= 5;
        if (numb==num){
            return true;
        }
        else return 5;
    }
}
``
```