# How do I get variables from one class to another to be used in a wrapper

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I was following the instructions found in the check marked response to the question found here:
[How to return 2 values from a Java method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function) in order to get two values back from a single function. Below is a portion of my main class where I set the two variables I need to pass to another class
The variables I want are searchURL and searchURLTwo. I might be able to send them with an intent but I have only used to send data which is used in another activity not sure who to use it to just send to another class that doesn't start a new activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.totlayout);

    //set the UI elements
    searchOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchOne);
    searchTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTwo);

    findMovies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findMovies);

    searchOne.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //make person search url1
            final StringBuilder personSearchURLOne = 
                     new StringBuilder(getName.getName1(searchOne)); 
            searchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.toString();

            return false;
        }
    });

    searchTwo.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //make person search url2
            final StringBuilder personSearchURLTwo = 
                   new StringBuilder(getName.getName2(searchTwo));
            searchURLTwo = personSearchURLTwo.toString();

            return false;
        }
    }); 
}
```

I want to use searchURLOne in the code below at jSon = new JSONParser:

```
public class getIDs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

public static String TAG_ID = "id";
public static String TAG_RESULTS = "results";



JSONArray results;
JSONObject jSon;
JSONObject jSon2;
public String firstID;
public String secondID;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... personSearchURLOne) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("params 0 in getIDs", personSearchURLOne[0]);
    try{
        jSon = new JSONParser().execute(personSearchURLOne[0]).get();

        results = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0; i<results.length(); i++){
            JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
            firstID = r.getString(TAG_ID);
            Log.d("firstID", firstID);

        jSon2 = new JSONParser().execute(personSearchURLOne[1]).get();

        results = jSon2.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int j=0; j<results.length(); j++){
            JSONObject r2 = results.getJSONObject(j);
            secondID = r2.getString(TAG_ID);

            }
        }


    }catch(InterruptedException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ExecutionException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
    return null;

}
  ublic String getFirstID(){
  return firstID;
  }
  public String getSecondID(){
  return secondID;
  }


}
```

I update the getIDs code to show the entire code and that doInBackground does not return a value instead there are two getter methods. The right URLs are passed in at personSearchURL[0] and [1]. From my main function I call getData which contains all of the execution logic for getting the search results from the api it is in getData that I call getIDs. Below is the relevant getData code:

```
 public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String> > {

String idOne;
String idTwo;
ArrayList<String> titleOne;
ArrayList<String> titleTwo;
ArrayList<String> myCommonFilms;

public static getIDs getMyIds(){

    return new getIDs();
}

/*public static Titles getMyTitles(String title){
    return new Titles();
}*/

protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.d("params in doinbackground contains", params[0]);
    Log.d("params in doinbackground contains", params[1]);

    new getIDs().execute(params[0], params[1]);

    //get ID 1 
    /*getIDs idholder = new getIDs().execute(params[0], params[1]);*/
    getIDs id1 = getMyIds();
    idOne = id1.getFirstID();
```

I need to know how to get the return value fo firstID from getIDs into my getData class.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created instance of class getIDs anywhere. I assume it will be created on some event handler function in the same activity that has the two EditTexts. Now you already have searchURLOne and searchURLTwo in this class.

> You need to call new getIDs().execute(searchURLOne,searchURLTwo);

Also you will be able to access the variables as follows

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... personSearchURLOne) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
            String searchURLOne = personSearchURLOne[0];
            String searchURLTwo = personSearchURLOne[1];
            /*this needs to be reference to searchURLOne*/
        jSon = new JSONParser().execute().get();

       }       
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that calling it that way will work because getIDs extends asynctask and the doinbackground doesnt return anything. Instead there are getter methods. I updated the code to show my entire getIDs class  and my getData class where I make the call to get first and second ID from the getters in getID but it is not working they are null.

Comment: You just have to change your getIDs class so that doInBackGround _does_ return values by changing `Void` to e.g. `String` in the `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String> >` part.

Comment: doing that will only let me return one value I need to return two.

Comment: create a class containing the two values that you want to return and return a new object of the class from doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following in your getData class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29

this will give the result of execution of the AsncTask

Comment: onPostExecute takes in the result of the doInBackground but I need to return two results thats why I had the getter methods because doInBackground will not let me return two results.

Comment: create a class containing the two values that you want to return and return a new object of the class from doInBackground()