# How do you return multiple types from calling a new instance of a class?

Tags: java, types, return, instance, output

From calling a new instance of the class

```
package main;
public class Word implements EditableTokenInterface{
    String token, tokenreadonly;
    public Word(String input){
        token = input;
    }
    public void setToken(String input){token = input;}
    public String getToken(){return token;}
    public String getTokenReadOnly(){
        tokenreadonly = token.toLowerCase();
        return tokenreadonly;
    }
}
```

using

```
BOTH OUTPUT TYPES = new Number(input.substring(start,end));
```

where `BOTH OUTPUT TYPES` are the `token` and `tokenreadonly` values.

How do return these values?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you want. `new` always returns one instance of the class whose constructor got invoked.

Comment: Different types or different values? `token` and `tokenreadonly` are both of type `String`, so I guess not types. For values, you can have a method return 2 (or any number of) values using any collection or array. You can't do this using `new` though.

Comment: Such as if you could do `Product, Sum = new ProductAndSum(5, 6)` where Product would be 30 and Sum would be 11

Comment: Related - [How to return 2 values from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function)