# Why cant i return another value? (JAVA)

Tags: java, return-value, static-methods

```
public static String split (String vector){
    String vector1 = "";
    String vector2 = "";
    final int SIZE = vector.length();
    int firsthalf = 0;
    int secondhalf = SIZE/2;
    while (firsthalf< SIZE/2){
        vector1+= vector.charAt(firsthalf);
        firsthalf++;
    }
    while (secondhalf< SIZE){
        vector2+= vector.charAt(secondhalf);
        firsthalf++;
    }
    return vector1;
    return vector2;

}
```

Hi 
so i know that this question might have been asked frequently by java noobs like myself but i dont understand why vector2 is out of reach as java error report calls it, and what can i do to return the vector2

Comment: Two things :

- a function returns a single value, no matter what. You can return "several" results by calling methods of the input arguments, which is called side-effects (tu populate a collection for example) or by wrapping them in a single object

- when `return` is found, any code following this return **in the same scope** will be ignored. It is called *dead code* and causes a compilation failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method can only have a single return value....your first return is vector1 ...hence vector2 is out of reach

consider this...

String result = split("TestVector");

using your method what is the value of result...

YOu could consider returning a List or Array of Strings.

Comment: then how else shoud i do to return two values?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate my answer covers some of what you need but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function