# Check for Winner Tic Tac Toe game Java

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

my check for winner method doesn't detect tie games. I don't understand where the problem is with the tie game, and searching through a column, so if anyone could help that would be great!.The code is below

```
public static boolean CheckForWinner(int player)
            {
                //Row and Column Check
                if (GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[0][2] == player ||
                    GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player ||
                    GameBoard[2][0] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player ||
                    GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[2][0] == player ||
                    GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player ||
                    GameBoard[0][2] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player)
                    {
                        finalwinner=true;
                        return true;
                    }

                //diagonal checks
                if (GameBoard[0][0]==player && GameBoard[1][1]==player && GameBoard[2][2]==player)
                {
                finalwinner=true;
                return true;
                }

                if (GameBoard[2][0]==player && GameBoard[1][1]==player && GameBoard[0][2]==player)
                {
                finalwinner=true;
                return true;
                }

                //Tie Game Check
                if (GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[0][2] == player &&
                    GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player &&
                    GameBoard[2][0] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player)
                    {
                tieGame=true;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

This is the main method:

```
       public static void main (String[] args)
                {
                System.out.println("Tic Tac Toe Game");
                System.out.println("Player 1 is 1, Computer is 2");

                Draw();
                currentplayer=1;
                while (winner!= true)
                {
                    if(currentplayer==1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your Turn");
                            Player1Turn(currentplayer);
                        }
                    else
                        ComputerTurn(currentplayer);

                    finalwinner=CheckForWinner(currentplayer);

                    if(finalwinner==true && tieGame==false)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Winner is Player" +currentplayer+ "Congrats Champion!");
                        System.out.println("Beginning New Game! Press Cancel then Enter to Exit");
                        Reset();
                    }

                    if(tieGame==true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("It's a Tie! Play Again.");
                        System.out.println("Beginning New Game! Press Cancel then Enter to Exit");
                        Reset();
                    }

                    if(currentplayer==1)
                        currentplayer=2;
                    else if(currentplayer==2)
                        currentplayer=1;
                }

                }
```

Comment: This code could greatly benefit from some `for` loops. This is way too repetitive.

Comment: i had for loops before but it wasn't working and after trying for so long I gave a settled for if statements

Comment: The simplest model of a TicTacToe board is a 9 slot array. Using a 2-d array version is unneeded complexity. Food for thought.

Comment: Another cool way to do this is to use `1` to represent the player, and `4` to represent the computer. Then you can add up a row/column/diagonal and derive meaning from that. `1` and `4` are useful because there won't be any overlaps in meaning when you add up different possible arrangements.

Comment: I've rolled back your question because when a question is solved, it is best to post an answer. If you don't want to do that, just leave an edit that it was solved. Deleting the question means the community can no longer benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this expression in the if statement:

```
GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[0][2] == player &&
                    GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player &&
                    GameBoard[2][0] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player
```

You're checking to see if the player is in every board position.

You want to determine that there wasn't a winner.  That means checking that none of the the rows, columns and diagonals have the same player.

Comment: but I have if statements to check diagonal, row and column wins, so the final possibility is if all the places are taken there hasn't been a winner declared because the other if statements didn't catch it, therefore there must be no winner and it's a tie game? Does that make sense, i don't know maybe my logic is flawed.

Comment: @JaneDoe You can detect a tie even earlier than that. If there is one X and one O in every row, column, and diagonal, the game is tied.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the "computer" won, if the computer didnt won, and player either, then you can turn the tieGame flag true

Answer (score 0):

Change `GameBoard[0][0] == player` to `GameBoard[0][0] != 0` for all 9 conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the main code/structure of the function. Your function needs to return two variables, finalwinner and tie game. Right now your function stops at the first return statement, and sets that equal to finalwinner in the main.

Try something like this:

```
public static boolean[] CheckForWinner(int player)
        {
            //Row and Column Check
            if (GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[0][2] == player ||
                GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player ||
                GameBoard[2][0] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player ||
                GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[2][0] == player ||
                GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player ||
                GameBoard[0][2] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player)
                {
                    boolean finalwinner=true;
                }

            //diagonal checks
            if (GameBoard[0][0]==player && GameBoard[1][1]==player && GameBoard[2][2]==player)
            {
                boolean finalwinner=true;
            }

            if (GameBoard[2][0]==player && GameBoard[1][1]==player && GameBoard[0][2]==player)
            {
                boolean finalwinner=true;
            }

            //Tie Game Check
            if (GameBoard[0][0] == player && GameBoard[0][1] == player && GameBoard[0][2] == player &&
                GameBoard[1][0] == player && GameBoard[1][1] == player && GameBoard[1][2] == player &&
                GameBoard[2][0] == player && GameBoard[2][1] == player && GameBoard[2][2] == player)
                {
                boolean tieGame=true;
            }
            return new boolean [] {finalwinner, tiegame};
        }

public static void main (String[] args)
                {
                System.out.println("Tic Tac Toe Game");
                System.out.println("Player 1 is 1, Computer is 2");
            Draw();
            currentplayer=1;
            while (winner!= true)
            {
                if(currentplayer==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your Turn");
                        Player1Turn(currentplayer);
                    }
                else
                    ComputerTurn(currentplayer);

                boolean result[] = CheckForWinner(currentplayer);

                if(result[0]==true && result[1]==false)
                {
                    System.out.println("Winner is Player" +currentplayer+ "Congrats Champion!");
                    System.out.println("Beginning New Game! Press Cancel then Enter to Exit");
                    Reset();
                }

                if(result[1]==true)
                {
                    System.out.println("It's a Tie! Play Again.");
                    System.out.println("Beginning New Game! Press Cancel then Enter to Exit");
                    Reset();
                }

                if(currentplayer==1)
                    currentplayer=2;
                else if(currentplayer==2)
                    currentplayer=1;
            }

            }
```

Comment: BTW, I think your logic in the CheckForWinner function is accurate.

Comment: how do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [Info on enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

This is probably not what you'd prefer, but I strongly suggest you go for a different move/board representation:

**HOW**

Firstly, I suggest you implement your board cells as enums (since there are only 9 of them).

Then, implement the board as a set of 9 enums, as such:

```
public enum Move {
A0, A1, A2, B0, B1, B2, C0, C1, C2; }
```

Also, implement winning patterns (e.g. a whole line, a whole diagonal) as sets of 3 enums (i.e. a subset of the board set).

After these changes, it gets a lot easier to check whether a player (be it you or computer) has won.

I recommend you add the subsets and the method that checks if a player has won inside the Move class as well.

A subset can be created like this:
e.g.

```
static private final EnumSet<Move> lineA = EnumSet.of(A0,A1,A2);
```

And a check from your won method (note you need to check for all subsets) could possibly be:

```
moves.containsAll(lineA)
```

where moves is the set of moves made by player (when a player makes a move you add the enum to it's moves set).

**WHY**

This design is more concise, straightforward and elegant. You should not experience the problems you described any longer, if you use this approach.

Comment: i'm pretty basic when it comes to java, I'm still a beginner hence I don't know what enums are, so I used a 2d array!

Comment: Then I refer you to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html . Enums are the better approach in your case so if I were you I would take the 10-15 mins required to read about and implement enums for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your main method you say `finalwinner=CheckForWinner(currentplayer);` so you don't have to set `finalwinner=true;` every time after checking row, column and diagonal. `return true;` is enough.

Your problem is, you check for a Tie Game and if it is the case, you also return true, but it is wrong, because neither player nor computer wins! So your checkForWinner method **always** returns **true**.

You don't really have to check extra for Tie Game. Just check win for player, check win for computer, if both are false and last move done - its a tie game.